# SVC-SOCCONN: xdmp:http-put

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

While I'm executing the below code in the Query console I'm getting an "SVC-SOCCONN" error. We are using the authentication method at the digest in the HTTP app server. please help me resolve this issue.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:http-put("http://example.com:8007/v1/documents?uri=my.xml",
     <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
       <authentication method="digest">
         <username>xxxx</username>
         <password>yyyyy</password>
       </authentication>
       <headers>
         <Content-type>application/xml</Content-type>
         <Accept>application/xml</Accept>
       </headers>
     </options>,
     <mydata>this is xml for the PUT body</mydata>)
```

Error:
[1.0-ml] SVC-SOCCONN: xdmp:http-put("http://example.com:8007/v1/documents?uri=my.xml", ........., this is xml for the PUT body) -- Socket connect error: wait xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49860: Timeout

Answer (score 0):

That would indicate that you cannot connect to that port. The error message is reporting port `49860` but you are attempting to communicate via `8007`.

Are there proxies involved?

Try hitting that http://example.com:8007 endpoint via your browser or using curl on that server that is running Query Console, to confirm that you can indeed connect to that endpoint.